# Not able to Install new software in eclipse neon 2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

When i am trying install new software in eclipse neon 2 I am getting error as "cannot complete your request.This installation has not been configured properly for software updates" and in error logs i can see logs as "Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclip"
After reinstalling ii works for the first time but after restarting the eclipse again I am facing same issue.

And I am not able to find   "Configuration" tab,setting "Support software installation in the launched application"

Kindly help,Thanks in Advance

Comment: "This installation has not been configured properly for software updates"...can you share some details about how it was installed?

Comment: Hi,I have updated my eclipse by eclipse Installer but I have also downloaded eclipse neon zip file in both the cases I am facing same issue.

Comment: I am getting the same problem after updating to neon.2. Software updates just stop working. I unzipped the Java EE 64B Neon.1 zip package on my windows machine. After I updated to Neon.2 software updates give the error mentioned in the post. Haven't been able to find a solution, so will just have to do a full reinstall :(